# Al abrir un Modal sobre otro, al segundo modal me hace scroll el body al tocar el segundo modal

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un modal que abro para hacer ciertas acciones, y tengo un boton en ese modal que abre otro modal, lo hago con bootstrap, ese boton lo que hace es ocultar el modal actual y muestra el siguiente con un data-dissmis:"modal", funciona todo bien. lo unico que cuando abro el segundo modal, el body hace scroll a medida que clickeo en el modal

```
                   <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="confirmarEquipo" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title">Equipos Recuperados</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="caja" id="caja">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="vaciarCaja" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Vaciar

                <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Salir
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
            </button>

            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-
```

target="#exampleModal">
Launch demo modal

```
                      <!-- MODAL FIRMAR -->

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

el boton launch demo modal me  cierra y abre el otro modal

```
                     <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria- 
 labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

que podria estar sucediendo? ese mismo modal que abro adentro de otro modal, lo abro normal en el doom sin abrirlo en otro modal, y me funciona bien si hacer scroll el body, obviamente al abrir el modal adentro del otro modal, se esta eliminando un propiedad o algo que hace q el modal no haga scroll

Comment: Parece que eso es problema del JS, deberia checar ahi. Ademas, pusiste mal tu codigo jeje.

Comment: Intenta aplicar la siguiente propiedad a la clase modal: `.modal { overflow: auto; }`